# How to deselect RadioButton so all Options 1,2,3 can be clear again

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

just in brief, RadioButtons in RadioGroup. Boolean with method case-if. Everything works and can be switched between three RadioButtons.

Question

How can I by clicking again on already selected RadioButton or by clicking anywhere on the screen, unclick this RadioButton so it can be unselected again. In general coming back to - ***three Options unselected and ready to choose***.

Thank you

Comment: RadioButtons are Buttons: use the Setter for selection and set all three to false.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Hello IQV. Because I'm just starting with Java and Android, can you please write some more about how to write this method in my case. Many thanks.

Comment: I've added the code. Thank you Toby.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `button.setChecked(false);` or group all of your buttons to RadioGroup then `RadioGroup.clearCheck();` whenever you want.

Comment: Hi Alperen :) Thank you .I tried these methods but every time I use 'setChecked' or 'clearCheck' I get it in red. How can I fix it and where put this method? - after all cases or in 'OnCreate' method?

Comment: 'RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Radio_Group);
        mRadioGroup.clearCheck();' .I placed it after all three switch-cases and when running I can't select any of the Radio Button now. Help :)